# I need my menu to go over an image

Tags: css, wordpress

Is there a way to move my main menu that is currently below the image, to overlap the image.

When I try and move the menu up, the image hides the menu. Note I am not referring to the menu at the top, that will be taken out soon. http://bethplummer.com/projectdemo/

Comment: Show us what you have tried already.

Answer (score 1):

The image hides your menu because it is called first, with `z-index` you can change this though. Add this to your css:

```
#menu-menu {
overflow: hidden;
margin-top: -76px;
position: relative;
z-index: 100;
}
```